# Why is my angular 10 default app won't show on IOS 9.3.5?

Tags: ios, angular, browser, ipad-2

I usually test my apps on my Ipad 2 that runs on `IOS 9.3.5` also I'm using angular 10.
I've just created a new app and when running it I get blank page on `Safari` and `Chrome`(I think they use the same webkit)

Looking at the console of `Safari` it says absolutely nothing.
I went through other types of similar questions on `SO`but can't find the solutions

the only thing I can say is that the basic html loads normally but with nothing inside `<app-root>`.

By the way the app is working just well on a recent `Android` phone.

Should I activate more polyfills?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've updated to angular 10
As mentioned by [@cjd82187](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178940/cjd82187) Angular doesn't take care natively old support based on `es5` everything is now `esm2015` so in order to make it work on my old Ipad I needed to add in my `ts.config.base.json`

```
"compilerOptions": {
     ...,
     target: 'es5',
     ...
}
```

I also added `safari 9`inside my `browserlistrc` file.

Answer (score 2):

Per the Angular docs, they only support the latest two major IOS Versions, which would be 13 and 12.

https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

If you have a Mac, you can try and debug in Safari, so you can see if there are any errors in the console to debug a little more.

1. From Safari on the Mac, go to Preferences > Advanced and you should see a checkbox at the bottom for "Show Develop menu in menu bar".
2. Connect your iphone via a cable to your computer
3. Open your site
4. Open Safari, look in the new develop bar, and you should see your phone listed

You should be able to debug your site from there.

Answer (score 0):

To whomever reads this after, a correction to JSmith's "solution". You gotta add the browser version you want to support to the `browserslist` file, but there is no need to change the target to es5 in `tsconfig.json`. In doing so, you will deactivate differential loading and lose its benefits.

Comment: Never worked for me. Haven't tested it with later version though